# How to move an Item's QRect

Tags: c++, qt, position, qrect

Is there any way to move a QRect object from its current position?

There are many functions (`moveTo`, `moveLeft`, …), but all of them move the object from (0,0), and not from its current position.

If I need to move my object from its current position by 5 in X-direction, available methods moves it first to (0,0), and then to (5,0);

But I need to move it from its actual position.

```cpp
int x_pos = item->rect.x();
int y_pos = item->rect.y();
x_pos -= 10;
y_pos -= 10;

item->rect.moveTo(x_pos, y_pos);
item->rect.setX(x_pos);
item->rect.setY(y_pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`QRect::translate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#translate).  In your particular case that would be something like...

```
item->rect.translate(-10, -10);
```

Or, if you want to leave the original `QRect` unmodified...

```
auto new_rect = item->rect.translated(-10, -10);
```